# How to detect whether a record ends with RS in AWK?

Tags: awk

In awk `$0` stands for the original line, with trailing RS striped.
But how do I know if the last line ends with a RS?

Comment: if the line doesn't ends with RS, then $0 would take all characters into the string until RS is encountered. So when you print $0 it always true that RS is encountered.

Comment: What about the final line of a input that ends with a EOF, not RS? @realspirituals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either of these should do it:

GNU awk:

```
gawk 'END{if (RT!="") print "found RS"}' file
```

Any awk (and assuming RS isn't set to the same value as your FS).

```
awk 'BEGIN{rs=RS;RS=FS} {last=$0} END{if (last ~ rs"$") print "found RS"}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the built-in `RT` variable is set to null. See:

http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Reading-Files

> If the input file ended without any text that matches RS, gawk sets RT to the null string.

Answer (score 2):

If the line doesn't ends with RS, then $0 would take all characters into the string until RS is encountered. 
So when you print $0 it always true that RS is encountered.

AWK default RS is single new line

To print the final line

```
awk -v max="$(wc -l < file)" 'FNR == max { print "Final line:",$0 }' file
```

You have your own options like have different characters for RS and EOF (END keyword)
or printing extra characters in your file by suffixing '0' for each RS encountered and '1' for the last line

```
cat input_file | sed 's/^/0/;$s/0/1/' | awk '{LST=/^1/;$0=substr($0,2)}
... your awk script in which you can use LST to check for the
... last line.'
```

Comment: The `END` block keeps the last line processed, wouldn't be more efficient to use it for your first case?

Comment: @Birei The END block only keeps the last line processed in SOME awks, not all of them. Even POSIX compliance doesn't require that feature.

Comment: @realspirituals It is not true to say `when you print $0 it always true that RS is encountered`. If RS is a newline and the input file does not end in a newline, for example, then $0 will still be populated for the last line exactly as if the file did end with a newline. Also, there's no need for a UUOC or sed when using awk.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thank you. I didn't know that, I thought that the `END` block was standard between all `awk` flavours.

Comment: @Birei - the `END` block is standard in all awks, it's the builtin variables that are available in the `END` block that varies between awk versions. POSIX requires that the `NF` from the last read record be available, but doesn't require the `$0` be available, for example.